# floats going from 0.2 to 0.19999994

Tags: java, javascript, arduino, processing

I am recording data every 0.02 seconds and my code to save this information to a tab deliminated file is producing some peculiar results where even though i am adding 0.02 on each time to the time variable it starts being slightly off (i'm aware that when rounded it is essentially the same but it bugs me). How do i get it to look like the corrected data set

```
output.println(time + "\t" + accelX + "\t" + accelY + "\t" + accelZ);
time = time + 0.02;
```

the output gives me (I left out the other data as it is going in fine)

```
Time 0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.099999994 0.1199999999
```

should be

```
Time 0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.1 0.12
```

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Why have you tagged your question `javascript`? Java and JavaScript are **very** different languages, running in **very** different environments.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP is using Processing, which was originally a Java framework, but has since been ported to JavaScript as well. That doesn't justify the tag, but I'd guess that's why it's there.

Comment: This is why it is there :) little bit confused as to which i was actually using

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, don't use float where double will work. Next of all, use printf instead of println, and specify your output's significant digits.

e.g. something like this,

```
output.printf("%5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f", time, accelX, accelY, accelZ);
```